# Rules Don't Execute

Tags: clips, expert-system

I have an expert system to figure out the corresponding animal. I have inserted all of the facts, however when I try to (run) the Expert System no question is asked, when the first question should be displayed as 'Is the animal big?' Does anyone have any idea please.
Many thanks in advance

```
(deffacts startup (animal mouse) (animal squirrel) (animal hamster) (animal giraffe) (animal elephant) (animal hippo) 
(animal rhino) (animal big) (neck-long giraffe) (nose-long elephant) (swim-alot hippo) (animal-squeak mouse) (tail-bushy squirrel))

=>

(defrule is-animal-big 

(not (animal-big ?)) 

=> (printout t "Is the animal big (yes or no)?") 

(assert (animal-big (read))))

(defrule yes-big-check-neck

(animal-big yes)

(not (neck-long ?))

=> 

(printout t "Is the animals neck long (yes or no)?")

(assert (neck-long (read))

)

(defrule neck-long-yes

(neck-long yes)

=>

(printout t "your animal is a giraffe" crlf)

(bind ?animal giraffe)

(assert (animal-is ? animal))

) 

;;;========================================

(defrule neck-long-no-check-nose

(neck-long no)

(not (nose-long ?))

=> 

(printout t "Is the animals nose long (yes or no)?")

(assert (nose-long (read))

)

(defrule nose-long-yes

(nose-long yes)

=>

(printout t "your animal is an elephant" crlf)

(bind ?animal elephant)

(assert (animal-is ? animal))

)

;;;=======================================

(defrule nose-long-no-check-swim

(nose-long no)

(not (swim-alot ?))

=>

(printout t "Does the animal swim a lot (yes or no)?")

(assert swim-alot (read((

)

(defrule swim-alot-yes

(swim-alot yes)

=>

(printout t "your animal is a hippo" crlf)

(bind ?animal hippo)

(assert (animal-is ? animal))

)

;;;=====================================

(defrule swim-alot-no

(swim-alot no)

=>

(printout t "your animal is a rhino" crlf)

(bind ?animal rhino)

(assert (animal-is ? animal))

)

;;;======================================

(defrule no-big-check-squeak

(animal-big no)

(not (animal-squeak ?))

=>

(printout t "Does the animal squeak (yes or no)?")

(assert animal-squeak (read))

)

(defrule animal-squeak-yes

(animal-squeak yes)

=>

(printout t "your animal is a mouse" crlf)

(bind ?animal mouse)

(assert (animal-is ? animal))

)

;;;=======================================

(defrule squeak-no-check-tail

(animal-squeak no)

(not (tail-bushy ?))

=>

(printout t "Is the animals tail bushy (yes or no)?")

(assert tail-bushy (read))

)

(defrule tail-bushy-yes

(tail-bushy yes)

=> 

(printout t "your animal is a squirrel" crlf)

(bind ?animal squirrel)

(assert (animal-is ? animal))

)

;;;=======================================

(defrule tail-bushy-no

(tail-bushy no)

=>

(printout t "your animal is a hamster" crlf)

(bind ?animal hamster)

(assert (animal is ? animal)))

;;;==============================

;;;******************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is riddled with syntax errors, but the **startup** deffacts and **is-animal-big** defrule compile without errors. You're probably not issuing a (reset) command to assert the facts within your deffacts before issuing a (run) command.